# Display 9000 Rows Using AJAX DataTables

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, microsoft-edge

So I have a web application that has **reporting module**. This module has Ajax code that gets 9000+ rows/data from the database (**project: as designed**). I tried using JQuery TableSorter but it gives a **long time** of data generation when performed in Edge Browser. I tried using DataTables since I found in the Google that DataTables can display data and it has sorting in headers as well. Please see this link: [DataTables Example](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html). And now I'm trying to to it on my code. But it seems like I can't make it functional. Sorry, I'm just a newbie in programming. **What I want is to display data into a table that is already returned through ajax call and that table can sort the columns like the example on the link I provided above.**

```
return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "generateCustomReportAction",
            data: saveReportSettingMap,
            beforeSend: function(data) {
                $("#custom-report-loader").dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    draggable: false,
                    dialogClass: "noclose",
                    create: function(event) {
                        $(event.target).parent().css("position", "fixed");
                    }
                });
            },
            success: function(data){
                $("#report-title").html($("#resultType option:selected").text());
                $(".report-table-container").empty().append(data);

                $('.reportTable').DataTable({
                    data: data
                });
```

And this code is for displaying the returned data from Ajax into a table. But this block of code do not work.

**$('.reportTable').DataTable({
    data: data
});**

This is the **error message** that I encountered upon running this module.
[image]

It says that: **DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0, column 1. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4** (for those who cannot view the image)

Comment: Any error on the console?

Comment: Hi. I've edited the question. I added the error message (dialog box). There is no error message in my eclipse nor in browser console.

Comment: Hi, can you able to debug using the inspect element?If yes can you break point on the success function and hover the data parameter and Post the return data and post the HTML Table you are using.. I think it says there is a column that is not set to the table that exist in data parameter but not sure yet until we see the return data and the html table you are using. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you are trying to say. I only know how to get the data returned in "network" but the action class must be done. In my situation, the generation of data don't work that's why I can't check the returned data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataTables warning: table id=table\_especie - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44599897/datatables-warning-table-id-table-especie-requested-unknown-parameter-0-for)