# DataTables warning: table id=table_especie - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I know this was asked hundreds of times, but I think my case is very specific and it needs someone who knows jQuery to help, or at least has seen this before!

I have this code to build a table called "especie:

HTML

```
<table class="table" id="table_especie">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th></th>
       <th></th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Script JS:

```
var tableEspecie= $('#table_especie').DataTable({
    "paging":   false,
    "info":     false,
    "order": [
        [2, "asc" ],
        [3, "asc"],
        [1, "asc"]
    ],
    "columnDefs": [
        { "visible": false, "targets": 0 },
        { "visible": false, "targets": 2 },
        { "visible": false, "targets": 3 }
    ],

    "drawCallback": function () {
        var api = this.api();
        var rows = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).nodes();
        var last=null;

        api.column(2, {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( especie, i ) {
            if ( last !== especie) {
                $(rows).eq( i ).before(
                    '<tr class="especie info"><td colspan="4">'+especie+'</td></tr>'
                );

                last = especie;
            }
        } );

        $("#table_especie thead").remove();
        $("#table_especie tfoot").remove();
    }
});

var populateEspecieShowName = function(data) {
    $('#animal_especie_name').text(data[0].name);
};


var populateEspecieTable = function(data) {
    var animais = [];

    $.each(data, function(id_animal, animal){
        animais.push([
            animal.id_animal,
            animal.nome_animal + ': ' + '<br>' + animal.notas_animal,
            animal.foto_animal
        ]);
    });

    $('#table_especie').dataTable().fnClearTable();
    $('#table_especie').dataTable().fnAddData(animais);
    $('#table_especie').dataTable().fnDraw();
};

$('#table_especie tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    var animalId = $('#table_especie').DataTable().row(this).data();

    if (animalId !== undefined)
        $.route('animal/' + animalId[0]);
});

$('#table_especie_search').keyup(function(){
    $('#table_especie').DataTable().search($(this).val(), false, true).draw() ;
});
```

Basically, it builds the table using data from a database! And I get the error (DataTables warning: table id=table_especie - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4) every time I go from table "especies" to table "especie". The error makes it sound like it's something wrong with "especie". What should I change to make the error go away? It still builds the table, but I get this error before. Thanks!!!

Comment: I am a little confused as to what you are trying to do. I see you removing the header, which  breaks DataTables.   Are you just trying to create dynamic columns?

Comment: Yes. So basically I am creating an app that will fetch data from a database (MySQL) and show it dynamically. It's an app to show animals from shelters, so it needs to be able to get the data from the local database, in case more animals are added/removed.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```json
"columnDefs": [{
    "defaultContent": "-",
    "targets": "_all"
}],
```

Comment: Although this may answer the question, some comments and/or explanation would be nice. That will help other users as well.

Comment: Now it doesn't show the error but it doesn't build the table, the error, when debugging with Chrome is:

jquery.dataTables.min.js:65 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined
    at W (jquery.dataTables.min.js:65)
    at ya (jquery.dataTables.min.js:70)
    at e (jquery.dataTables.min.js:91)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:93)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
and more...